# Auto-size home icon bar

Tags: css, wagtail

I'm using an app for add video support to ***Wagtail***: ***wagtail-embed-videos***. 
This app add a new icon in the icon bar but is not properly sized, i mean, 
icon isn't in the same line, is putted in the botton.

[image]

I want icon in the same line, like this:

[image]

In order to put all icons in the same line we can change the ***width*** value; make permanent this change require recompile statics, ok.

My question is, have we make it by own hand or you can add support for more 
than three icons in the icon bar?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is for Wagtail staff, but I think it doesn't matter, because only this package add a new media icon.

Comment: How about using tampermonkey extension to solve the problem?

Comment: What's it? I think this feature concerns to `Wagtail` staff.